# Vision Cone for Enemy AI in Unity 2d

Tags: unity, 2d

I am trying to develop an Enemy AI with vision cone in unity 2d top down game, can you please suggest me some approach or sample script, so I can get an idea.

Answer (score 1):

In the Enemy script Update

//assuming a as half of your vision cone angle

```
    //pseudo code
    foreach target {
        if (Vector3.Angle(target.position-trasform.position,trasform.forward) < a){
            //then target is inside vision cone
            //next you can check vision distance ...
            //next you can check obstacles with a raycast ....
        }
     }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The Unity documentation has a good example on how to achieve this with a useful example.

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Angle.html (example included below for illustration purposes)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    public Transform target;
    void Update() {
        Vector3 targetDir = target.position - transform.position;
        Vector3 forward = transform.forward;
        float angle = Vector3.Angle(targetDir, forward);
        if (angle < 5.0F)
            print("close");

    }
}
```

Essentially what you are doing is calculating the angle between the enemy and the target.  You achieve this through getting the forward vector of the enemy and then using Vector3.Angle to calculate the angle. Once you have this value you can then check if the angle is less than whatever angle you want to be the enemy's field of vision. If the angle is less than your field of vision then the target is in the enemy's field of vision.

This in itself is enough to provide a reasonable detection system but you may also want to factor in distance from the enemy (as the enemy may be short sighted?)  This can be easily discovered through the use of the rather nifty Vector3.Distance function which is used as shown below.

```
var dist = Vector3.Distance(target.position, enemy.position);
```

Providing both of these values gives your enemy detection cone a look similar to the diagram below.

[image: detection cone with distance]